# Condensing code inside columns with py simple gui

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I'm trying to make a small program that you can enter names into places, assign scores, then save and show the data.

It currently works using this code

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
col1 = [
    [sg.Push(), sg.Text('Insert Names Here'), sg.Push()],
    [sg.Text('1st '), sg.Push(), sg.Input('', key='-1place-', size=(30), do_not_clear=False)],
    [sg.Text('2nd '), sg.Push(), sg.Input('', key='-2place-', size=(30), do_not_clear=False)],
    [sg.Push(), sg.Button('Calculate'), sg.Push()],
]
col2 = [
    [sg.Text('Points')],
    [sg.Input('', key='-1points-', size=(5, 30))],
    [sg.Input('', key='-2points-', size=(5, 30))],
    [sg.Button('Save')]
]
col3 = [
    [sg.Push(), sg.Text('Rankings'), sg.Push()],
    #insert table here
    [sg.Push(), sg.Button('Refresh Scores'), sg.Button('Open to Print'), sg.Push()]
]
layout = [
    [
        sg.Column(col1),
        sg.VSeparator(),
        sg.Column(col2),
        sg.VSeparator(),
        sg.Column(col3),
        ]
] 
window = sg.Window("Shooter Rankings", layout)
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
```

the problem is now I need to track the top 20 names and repeating that code is pretty bulky so I tried changing the first column to this but keep getting errors.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
def NameBox(num):
    return [sg.Text(str(num)),sg.Push(), sg.Input(key=f"-{num}place-", size=(30), do_not_clear=False)]
col1 = [
    [sg.Push(), sg.Text('Insert Names Here'), sg.Push()],
    [NameBox(x) for x in range(5)],
    [sg.Push(), sg.Button('Calculate'), sg.Push()],
]
```

am I missing something simple or do I just need to list them all out individually?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirm the format of layout is in `List[List[Element]] | Tuple[Tuple[Element]]`.

```py
col1 = [
    [sg.Push(), sg.Text('Insert Names Here'), sg.Push()]] + [
     NameBox(x) for x in range(5)] + [
    [sg.Push(), sg.Button('Calculate'), sg.Push()],
]
```

Comment: Thank you this solved the problem I was having. I tried concatenating but was unable to get it too work but now I see where I formatted wrong.